# Oracle SQL trigger results in compilation error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a problem with trigger not working. Here is my trigger code

```
create or replace trigger "ZIVOTINJE_T2"
BEFORE
insert or update on "ZIVOTINJE"
for each row
begin
IF new.cijena>10 THEN
    :new.cijena:=9.9

ELSEIF new.cijena<0 THEN
    :new.cijena:=0.1
END IF;
end;
```

When I try to insert entity in table ZIVOTINJE, I get this

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'DENISS.ZIVOTINJE_T2' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

Comment: The message indicates one or more syntax errors in your trigger code. Please look at the documentation to resolve these things.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#ADFNS012

Answer (score 5):

I can see three problems in the code of your trigger:

- You need to refer to the new values of the row using `:new` (including the colon), not `new`.
- To change values that are about to be inserted/updated, write `:new.cijena := 9.9;` instead of `SET new.cijena=9.9`.  Note that (a) there is no `SET` keyword here; (b) the assignment operator is `:=`, not `=`; and (c) you need a semi-colon at the end of the line.
- Use `ELSIF` instead of `ELSEIF`.

Finally, in SQL*Plus, you can use `SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER "ZIVOTINJE_T2"` to show the errors for this trigger.

Comment: i did the things you said, now code looks like this

create or replace trigger "ZIVOTINJE_T2"
BEFORE
insert or update on "ZIVOTINJE"
for each row
begin
IF new.cijena>10 THEN
    :new.cijena:=9.9;

ELSEIF new.cijena<0 THEN
    :new.cijena:=0.1;
END IF;
end;

it still gives me same error message

Comment: @user1189428: you haven't done everything I said.  You didn't change `ELSEIF` to `ELSIF`, and there are still two `new`s without a leading colon (just before the `>10` and `<0`).  Also, please avoid posting too much code in comments.  Edit your question to add the modified code instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "ZIVOTINJE_T2"
BEFORE
insert or update on "ZIVOTINJE"
for each row
begin
  IF :new.cijena = 10 THEN
    :new.cijena := 9.9;
  ELSE
    IF :new.cijena < 0 THEN
      :new.cijena := 0.1;
    END IF;
  end if;
end;